# Pebble C convert char to int

Tags: c, pebble-sdk

I have read a lot of ideas how to convert a single char of a string to an integer but I'm struggling with pointers in C. I am guessing at something like:

```
strftime(buffer, sizeof("0000"), "%H%M", tick_time);
onedigit = atoi(&buffer[1]);
```

So I want to have the first digit of the time converted into an integer.

If you have a more "elegant" way to do it - let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first character as an integer you want:

```
onedigit = buffer[0] - '0';
```

This takes the first (usually ASCII) character, subtracts the (ASCII) value for `0`, leaving you with an integer value in the range 0..9.

You can easily do the same thing for other numeric characters in the string, e.g. to get the tens digit:

```
tensdigit = buffer[1] - '0';
```

Comment: Cool - I'll look out for your first Pebble app/watchface !